# I have a check box inside an user control. I put the user control inside page 5th time. the check box only works first time

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an check box inside an user control,I put the user control inside webpage 5th time. but only one check box works and effect in all user control inside this page, the other 4th check box not work.So how to make each check box work independently or separated.
here is the user control:

```
<div dir="rtl" id='<%=uniqueKey %>'>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkGregDate" runat="server" name="cland" value="1" />ميلادي
    <input type="text" id="txtHijri_Date" runat="server" style="width: 90px" />
    <input type="text" id="txtHijri_Date_EN" runat="server" style="width: 90px" />
    <a id="imgCalendar" onclick="x<%=uniqueKey %>();">
        <img id="imgCalendarss" src="../images/Smallcalendar.png" height="27px" alt='' />
    </a>
</div>
```

The Jquery Function:

```
jQuery(function() {
     jQuery('#<%=chkGrog.ClientID%>').change(
   function () {
   if (jQuery('#<%=chkGrog.ClientID%>').is(':checked')){
            jQuery('#<%=txtHijri_Date_EN.ClientID %>').show();
        jQuery('#<%=txtHijri_Date.ClientID %>').hide();
    } else {
        jQuery('#<%=txtHijri_Date_EN.ClientID %>').hide();
        jQuery('#<%=txtHijri_Date.ClientID %>').show();
    }
 }).change();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to pass the correct client id to your user control. If you are using .NET 4.0 and above you could use the static mode --> SET `ClientIDMode="Static"`.

For example:
`<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />`.

Otherwise you will need to pass the client id.

*Keep in mind the client id is changing dynamically based on the container page.*

```
$(# + ClientId + "txtGreg_Date_EN").show();
```

**EDIT**

Since you are using .NET 4 update TextBoxes in your user control to

```
<input type="text" id="txtHijri_Date" runat="server" style="width: 90px" ClientIDMode="Static" />
<input type="text" id="txtGreg_Date_EN" runat="server" style="width: 90px" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Comment: I use .Net 4.0. Please more clarification

Comment: thanks alot for your participation, this feature not availble (ClientIDMode="Static") and the main problem in the check box event!!

Comment: You textboxes are server controls, you will need to use the full id. The client id along with the textbox name.

Comment: Thanks alot, it is working now, and here is the modification:

Comment: jQuery(function () {
        jQuery('#<%=chkGrog.ClientID%>').change(
   function () {
       if (jQuery('#<%=chkGrog.ClientID%>').is(':checked')) {
            jQuery('#<%=txtHijri_Date_EN.ClientID %>').show();
            jQuery('#<%=txtHijri_Date.ClientID %>').hide();
        } else {
            jQuery('#<%=txtHijri_Date_EN.ClientID %>').hide();
            jQuery('#<%=txtHijri_Date.ClientID %>').show();
        }


    }).change();

   });

Comment: user control modification:

Comment: <div dir="rtl" id='<%=uniqueKey %>'>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkGrog" runat="server" name="cland" value="1" />ميلادي
    <input type="text" id="txtHijri_Date" runat="server" style="width: 90px" />
    <input type="text" id="txtHijri_Date_EN" runat="server" style="width: 90px" />
    <a id="imgCalendar" onclick="x<%=uniqueKey %>();">
        <img id="imgCalendarss" src="../images/Smallcalendar.png" height="27px" alt='' />
    </a>
</div>

Comment: please could you adivce me why this option (ClientIDMode="Static") not avaiable although I use .Net 4., by the way it is working without add this option.

Comment: Khalid, would you add the code to the original post please? It's not a good idea to have the code in the comments it's not readable.

Comment: About your question. Check this out buddy http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Nov/07/ClientIDMode-in-ASPNET-40